# Efficiently having mulitple facebook like buttons on one page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, button, facebook-like

I have about 20 Facebook Like buttons on one page - each referring to a different url.

When I take a look at the performance of my page, each of this like buttons is downloading a .js file:

https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3iSgH4/y5/l/en_US/yGeRhgWiqPf.js

The file itself is only 104 KB big, but downloaded 20 times is already 2 MB.

This is how I created the like buttons:

This code ONCE on the page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And this code for each button:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://example.com/post/1" 
         data-layout="button"></div>
```

I haven't found a way yet to download the .js ONCE only and reduce the amount of traffic (My entire page is 3.9MB in size and 2.4 MB of that are scripts)

Thanks for any advice!!

Comment: I take it you've checked that the file is actually downloaded 20 times, and not cached at all

Comment: check out the asynchronous way to load the js sdk, it´s in the docs.